# Type hint for a module containing constants

Tags: python, pyright

I have a config.py file which has a list of constants, such as:

```py
# config.py
NAME = 'John'
AGE = 23
```

In another file, I import this file as a module and then pass it as a parameter to other functions. I used ModuleType as the type for this parameter.

```py
import config
from types import ModuleType
def f1(config: ModuleType) -> None:
    print(config.NAME)
```

The problem is when I run pyright linter, it reports an error:

```
 79:30 - error: Cannot access member "NAME" for type "ModuleType"
    Member "NAME" is unknown (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

What's the correct way to type hint the config to avoid these errors?

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this to test, but I'm not able to find typing.ModuleType anywhere. I've looked at the docs as well, but nothing is there either. How did you get yours?

Comment: Because there is no `ModuleType` in typing. `from types import ModuleType`. And I do not find a problem after importing `ModuleType` from `types`.

Comment: @12944qwerty yes, it's supposed to be `types` not `typing`

Comment: @m.i.cosacak Yes, I found as much. But somehow OP is able to get it from typing... unless the linter doesn't recognize that ModuleType isn't from typing. Has OP run the file with python or just through the linter?

Comment: Hm, I just tested this by importing with `types` and it seems to work. I think this question can be answered by a typo fix, correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's typo and the linter doesn't recognise ModuleType isn't from typing. However, when I import ModuleType from types, I still got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easiest and most convenient way to handle this is to just not annotate the `config` argument, or annotate it as `Any`. You *can* provide a more specific annotation, but it gets extremely awkward.

The problem with your existing annotation is that your `f1` is annotated as taking arbitrary modules as arguments, and arbitrary modules may not have a `NAME` attribute. (Also `ModuleType` is in `types`, not `typing`.) A correct, specific annotation for `f1` would specify that it takes something with a `NAME` attribute, which you can specify with a custom protocol class:

```
import typing

class HasName(typing.Protocol):
    NAME: str

def f1(config: HasName) -> None:
    print(config.NAME)
```

but you'll have to do this for everything you want to define in `config`, and it'll get even more awkward if you want to allow optional config definitions in `config`.

Also, if you try to pass `config` as an argument to `f1` now, it *still* won't work, because when you pass a module as an argument, mypy treats it as just a generic module, and doesn't consider its contents. (I don't know what pyright does, but that's how mypy handles it.) You would have to explicitly cast `config`:

```
f1(typing.cast(HasName, config))
```

which is extremely awkward. Plus, once you have this cast in place, mypy won't report an error even if `config` *doesn't* have a `NAME` attribute, so you've gained no safety at all from all this awkward work.

Comment: Setting the type as Any seems to have solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

As it turns out, all modules are subtypes of `types.ModuleType` and therefore `typing.ModuleType`.  Thus, what you want is:

```
def f1(config: config) -> None:
    print(config.NAME)
```

The first `config` is just a formal parameter, the second refers to the module by name.  The `typing` module will actually import the members, and it all works.

This does make me wonder what is the point of this.  If the module has to be imported in order for the function to be defined, then why pass it as a parameter at all?

Comment: No, modules are *instances* of `types.ModuleType`, not subtypes. Modules are not types.

Comment: If you try specifying a module as a type, mypy [reports](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.9&gist=0fa1bd3e28115cce6f5a1f0c7f980148) `error: Module "whatever" is not valid as a type`.

Comment: OK, I see where I went wrong when I was experimenting with this.  The code I included runs, but it's not right.  Perhaps I should leave this as a bad example.

Answer (score -1):

### Working as of September, 2023

```
from typing import Final

UPGRADE : Final[str] = "upgrade"
DOWNGRADE: Final[str] = "downgrade"
```